# Uncaught ReferenceError: AOS is not defined

Tags: javascript, chaos

I used [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/). I am trying to add the AOS library but it's showing me the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: AOS is not defined` and the aos-animate class doesn't apply.

I have also included files in CSS and JS.

**script.js**

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/themes/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/themes/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/themes/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/themes/js/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.lazy').Lazy();
    });
</script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/themes/js/aos.js"></script>
<script>
    AOS.init();
</script>
```

I see this error in the console.

HTML

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3" data-aos="fade-in">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrD0y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by the version you imported. Check your code by importing different aos versions from
[AOS Github](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos).